# Combine similar rows to one row in python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pandasql

I have some dataframe as below, what I want to do is to combine the rows with same 
"yyyymmdd" and "hr " into one  row.
(there are several rows with same "yyyymmdd" and  "hr" )

```
       yyyymmdd  hr ariel cat kiki mmax vicky gaolie shiu nick ck
10   2015-12-27   9     0   0    0    0     0      0    0   23  0
181  2015-12-27  10     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    2  0
65   2015-12-27  11     0   0    0    0     0      0    0   20  0
4    2015-12-27  12     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    4  0
0    2015-12-27  17     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    2  0
141  2015-12-27  19     1   0    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
160  2015-12-28   8     0   8    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
82   2015-12-28   9     0   0    0    0     0      0   19    0  0
113  2015-12-28   9    11   0    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
180  2015-12-28   9     0  11    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
9    2015-12-28  10     0  13    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
76   2015-12-28  10    85   0    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
107  2015-12-28  10     0   0    0    0     0      0   15    0  0
188  2015-12-28  10     0   0    0    0     2      0    0    0  0
34   2015-12-28  11     0   0    0    0     0      0   14    0  0
69   2015-12-28  11     0   0    0    0     2      0    0    0  0
134  2015-12-28  11     0  11    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
158  2015-12-28  11     2   0    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
```

part of the output I want should like this  for instance:

```
    yyyymmdd  hr ariel cat kiki mmax vicky gaolie shiu nick ck
2015-12-28  10     85   13    0    0     2      0    15    0  0
```

please share some ideas that I can use in python pandas or SQL, thanks!

=========================================================================

Now I have 2 more question want to ask :

1. how can I "fill" the "hr" index  of the dataframe ?
   it suppose should be something like this :

   `yyyymmdd  hr ariel cat kiki mmax vicky gaolie shiu nick ck
   0   2015-12-27   8   NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   1   2015-12-27   9    0  0   0    0     0      0   0    23  0
   2   2015-12-27  10    0  0    0    0     0      0   0    2  0
   3   2015-12-27  11    0  0    0    0     0      0   0   20  0
   4  2015-12-27  12     0  0    0    0     0      0   0    4  0
   5  2015-12-27  13     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   6  2015-12-27  14     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   7  2015-12-27  15     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   8  2015-12-27  16    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   9  2015-12-27  17    0   0    0   0     0      0    0    2  0
   10  2015-12-27  18    NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   11  2015-12-27  19     1   0    0   0     0      0    0    0  0
   12  2015-12-27  20     NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
   13   2015-12-28   8     0   8    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
   14  2015-12-28   9    11  11    0    0     0      0   19    0  0
   15  2015-12-28  10    85  13    0    0     2      0   15    0  0
   16  2015-12-28  11     2  11    0    0     2      0   14    0  0
   17  2015-12-28  12     2  20    0    4     0      0   10    0  0
   18  2015-12-28  13     8   9    0    9     3      0    9    0  0
   19  2015-12-28  14     4  10    0    8     0      0   22    0  0
   20  2015-12-28  15     3   3    0    2     0      0   16    0  0
   21  2015-12-28  16    14   5    1    1     0      0   19    0  0
   22  2015-12-28  17    15   1    2    0     0      0   19    0  0
   23  2015-12-28  18     0   0    0    6     0      0    0    0  0
   24  2015-12-28  19     0   0    0    5     0      0    0    0  0
   25  2015-12-28  20     0   0    0    1     0      0    0    0  0`
2. how can I plot the line charts based on columns and hr ?
   (x-axis = columns , i.e. :  ariel ,cat, kiki...)
   (y-axis = hr, i.e. : 8,9,10...20 )
   every chart represents one data (i.e. 2015-12-27, 2015-12-28..)

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using an sql database?  or Is this just some sort of spreadsheet file?

Comment: hi Zabari , 
I used SQL first , then import the data into python pandas

Comment: I'd suggest asking new questions one at a time as new questions, this one you already marked as answered

Comment: hi Ezer K , thanks for your suggestion, I'll do that later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data into a Pandas dataframe, and then groupby and get the max of each group,
Copy-Pasting your example into a csv, it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv',index_col=0)
df_combined = df.groupby(['yyyymmdd','hr']).max()
df_combined
```

Output:

[image]

Use reset_index() in case you don't want the multi-index.

Comment: Hi Ezer K,  thanks for the way you shared! it works!!!
(and also thanks for the   "reset_index()" you shared, it just make my dataframe clearer)