# How to fill the indexs of dataframe & make the subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Following the question I asked: [Combine similar rows to one row in python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567798/combine-similar-rows-to-one-row-in-python-dataframe])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYnh.png)

I have the original data below, and  have 2 questions want to ask :

```
yyyymmdd  hr ariel cat kiki mmax vicky gaolie shiu nick ck
0   2015-12-27   9     0   0    0    0     0      0    0   23  0
1   2015-12-27  10     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    2  0
2   2015-12-27  11     0   0    0    0     0      0    0   20  0
3   2015-12-27  12     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    4  0
4   2015-12-27  17     0   0    0    0     0      0    0    2  0
5   2015-12-27  19     1   0    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
6   2015-12-28   8     0   8    0    0     0      0    0    0  0
7   2015-12-28   9    11  11    0    0     0      0   19    0  0
8   2015-12-28  10    85  13    0    0     2      0   15    0  0
9   2015-12-28  11     2  11    0    0     2      0   14    0  0
10  2015-12-28  12     2  20    0    4     0      0   10    0  0
11  2015-12-28  13     8   9    0    9     3      0    9    0  0
12  2015-12-28  14     4  10    0    8     0      0   22    0  0
13  2015-12-28  15     3   3    0    2     0      0   16    0  0
14  2015-12-28  16    14   5    1    1     0      0   19    0  0
15  2015-12-28  17    15   1    2    0     0      0   19    0  0
16  2015-12-28  18     0   0    0    6     0      0    0    0  0
17  2015-12-28  19     0   0    0    5     0      0    0    0  0
18  2015-12-28  20     0   0    0    1     0      0    0    0  0
```

1. how can I "fill" the "hr" index  of the `DataFrame`? The result should be something like this:

   `yyyymmdd   hr  ariel   cat kiki    mmax    vicky   gaolie  shiu    nick    ck
   12/27/15    8   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   23  0
   12/27/15    10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0
   12/27/15    11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   20  0
   12/27/15    12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0
   12/27/15    13  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    14  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    15  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    16  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    17  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0
   12/27/15    18  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/27/15    19  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   12/27/15    20  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   12/28/15    8   0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   12/28/15    9   11  11  0   0   0   0   19  0   0
   12/28/15    10  85  13  0   0   2   0   15  0   0
   12/28/15    11  2   11  0   0   2   0   14  0   0
   12/28/15    12  2   20  0   4   0   0   10  0   0
   12/28/15    13  8   9   0   9   3   0   9   0   0
   12/28/15    14  4   10  0   8   0   0   22  0   0
   12/28/15    15  3   3   0   2   0   0   16  0   0
   12/28/15    16  14  5   1   1   0   0   19  0   0
   12/28/15    17  15  1   2   0   0   0   19  0   0
   12/28/15    18  0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0
   12/28/15    19  0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0
   12/28/15    20  0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0`
2. how can I plot the line charts based on columns and hr ?
3. x-axis = columns , i.e. :  ariel ,cat, kiki...
4. y-axis = hr, i.e. : 8,9,10...20
5. every `subplot` represents one date (i.e. 2015-12-27, 2015-12-28..)

and here is the framework of the  plot I want to get :
[please click here for the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYnh.png)

Comment: Do you want one subplot per date, or per data and column?

Comment: hi , @Stefan I  want to plot one subplot per date, 
for example :  
plot A :  2015-12-27 , x-axis :  hr  , y -axis : ariel...ck  
plot B :  2015-12-28 , x-axis :  hr  , y -axis : ariel...ck
...
plot E: 2015-12-31 , x-axis :  hr  , y -axis : ariel...ck

Comment: and please take this as reference :
http://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYnh.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `yyyymmdd` to `datetime`, combine with the `hr` information and then `resample` to hourly frequency like so:

```
df.yyyymmdd = pd.to_datetime(df.yyyymmdd)
df.yyyymmdd = df.apply(lambda x: x.yyyymmdd + pd.DateOffset(hours = x.hr), axis=1)
df.set_index('yyyymmdd', inplace=True)
df = df.resample('H')
```

to get:

```
                     hr  ariel  cat  kiki  mmax  vicky  gaolie  shiu  nick  ck
yyyymmdd                                                                      
2015-12-27 09:00:00   9      0    0     0     0      0       0     0    23   0
2015-12-27 10:00:00  10      0    0     0     0      0       0     0     2   0
2015-12-27 11:00:00  11      0    0     0     0      0       0     0    20   0
2015-12-27 12:00:00  12      0    0     0     0      0       0     0     4   0
2015-12-27 13:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 14:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 15:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 16:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 17:00:00  17      0    0     0     0      0       0     0     2   0
2015-12-27 18:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 19:00:00  19      1    0     0     0      0       0     0     0   0
2015-12-27 20:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 21:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 22:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-27 23:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 00:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 01:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 02:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 03:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 04:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 05:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 06:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 07:00:00 NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   NaN NaN
2015-12-28 08:00:00   8      0    8     0     0      0       0     0     0   0
2015-12-28 09:00:00   9     11   11     0     0      0       0    19     0   0
2015-12-28 10:00:00  10     85   13     0     0      2       0    15     0   0
2015-12-28 11:00:00  11      2   11     0     0      2       0    14     0   0
2015-12-28 12:00:00  12      2   20     0     4      0       0    10     0   0
2015-12-28 13:00:00  13      8    9     0     9      3       0     9     0   0
2015-12-28 14:00:00  14      4   10     0     8      0       0    22     0   0
2015-12-28 15:00:00  15      3    3     0     2      0       0    16     0   0
2015-12-28 16:00:00  16     14    5     1     1      0       0    19     0   0
2015-12-28 17:00:00  17     15    1     2     0      0       0    19     0   0
2015-12-28 18:00:00  18      0    0     0     6      0       0     0     0   0
2015-12-28 19:00:00  19      0    0     0     5      0       0     0     0   0
2015-12-28 20:00:00  20      0    0     0     1      0       0     0     0   0
```

You could plot the result as follows - assuming that you are looking for one subplot for each `date` and `column`:

```
for d, data in df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')):
    data.plot.line(figsize=(10, 20), sharey=True)
    plt.gcf().savefig('cats {}.png'.format(d), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

to get:
[image]

Comment: Hi Stefan , thanks for your idea !!  based on your answer,  I want to ask 

1. can you make the plot with same “scale division" in y-axis?
(i.e. all plots' y-axis are from 0 to 90 for example )

2. make all users with same data in one plot 
(i.e. 
plot A : 2015-12-27 , x-axis : hr , y -axis : ariel...ck
plot B : 2015-12-28 , x-axis : hr , y -axis : ariel...ck ..
.
.
plot E: 2015-12-31 , x-axis : hr , y -axis : ariel...ck

Comment: and please take this as reference : i.stack.imgur.com/lWYnh.png

Comment: hey Stefan, thank for your updated answer !
It works !! but I  think the code  should be `plt.gcf().savefig('cats {}.png'.format('D'), bbox_inches='tight')` , but not  `plt.gcf().savefig('cats {}.png'.format(d), bbox_inches='tight')`